# Difference between resolvent and degeneracy

Tags: entropy, quantum-gravity, matrix-model

I am studying https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.11115. In equation (62), the resolvent is defined as the integral transform of partition function as
$$
R(E) = -\int_0^\infty d\beta\ e^{\beta E} Z(\beta)
$$
This transformation looks familiar to me in calculating black hole entropy which is also the same transformation of partition function.

Then my question is that: is the degeneracy/exponential of entropy the same physical quantity as this resolvent?
Of course, this question should be asked in some specific model. For example, considering the matrix model of N=4 SYM which counts the black hole entropy. I can of course define quantity like (62) but such calculation is counting the black hole entropy rather than something called resolvent. So I don't understand their differences.

Answer (score 0):

By the resolvent they mean
$$
R(E)= {\rm Tr}\{(H-E)^{-1})\}
$$
which is an analytic function of $E$ with poles at the eigenvalues of $H$ (or a cut for a continuous spectim).  I don't see an obvious connection with the canonical enesmble entropy
$$
S= \frac U T +\ln Z = -\sum_n p_n \ln p_n,  \quad p_n = Z^{-1}e^{-\beta E_n}
$$
In the entropy  $U=\langle H \rangle= \sum_n p_n E_n$ is the internal energy, whereas in the resolvent $E$ is a parameter unrelated to the internal energy.